# Sql Join that Joins with the latest record

Tags: sql, function, join, union

I have two tables, one called Event with the following datatypes:

```
 CustomerID int
 eventId int
 eventDate datetime
 eventtype varchar(20)
```

and another called Activity with the following dataypes.

```
 CustomerID int,
 ActivityId,
 activitytime datetime
```

you can find the example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ddbf/4

my goal was to take each activity and append to the end of it the eventId and current state of eventtype which is dependent on timestamp

For example: an output for a row would be

```
CUSTOMERID----------TIMESTAMP----------- EVENTTYPE-----eventID  
141----------------2012/02/08 12:14:35.697-----Packaging-----------1
```

I tried to do a join and a union but would end up with either a table with a permutation of each activity tied to every single possible combination of the event type. Or with the union I was able to get a table that merged the two tables and filled the blank spots with n/a,  My guess is im going to have to write a function that i can pass in the date and then find the nearest event before a specified date.

Answer (score 0):

you can do group by on the event id and get latest information for that event

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26199/2

```
SELECT E.CustomerID, 
       MAX(A.activitytime) as TIMESTAMP,
       MAX(E.eventtype) as EventType,
       E.eventID
FROM Event E
JOIN Activity A
ON E.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
GROUP BY E.CustomerID, E.EventId
```